# Rails belongs_to class_name params permit

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a model: Media that is handling all attachments (with paperclip). What I'm trying to do is create in essence an attribute that pulls from the Media in a different model: Section.

So in my Section model I have the following:

```
Section
 belongs_to :policy, class_name: 'Media',
 optional: true,
 foreign_key: :policy_id
```

Then in my form view I have the following:

```
= f.tb_select :policy, options_from_collection_for_select(text_docs, :id, :attachment_file_name), include blank: 'Select Policy'
```

The drop down works and only the files I want from my helper method appear. However when I go to save I get:

> ActionController::UnpermittedParameters (found unpermitted parameter:
>   :policy):
>   app/controllers/admin/sections_controller.rb:48:in `section_params'
>   app/controllers/admin/sections_controller.rb:32:in`update'

My controller has the following in the params:

```
def section_params
 params.require(:region).permit(:name,  :text_to_order,
  location_ids: [], logo_ids: [], employee_ids: [])
end
```

I've tried the following in my params:

- :policy and I end up with

> ActiveRecord::AssociationTypeMismatch (Media(#70307010602740)
>   expected, got "13" which is an instance of String(#70306928901880))

- :policy_id and I end up with

> ActionController::UnpermittedParameters (found unpermitted parameter:
>   :policy)

- policy_ids: [] and I end up with

> ActionController::UnpermittedParameters (found unpermitted parameter:
>   :policy)

Beyond creating a new attribute how can I assign a faux attribute that connects to a different model and save it?

Comment: You should use policy_id in both the form and the params whitelist.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

change

`= f.tb_select :policy, options_from_collection_for_select(text_docs, :id, :attachment_file_name), include blank: 'Select Policy'`

to

`= f.tb_select :policy_id, options_from_collection_for_select(text_docs, :id, :attachment_file_name), include blank: 'Select Policy'`

and add `:policy_id` to `section_params`. Basically when you select an option from select it take the option value as selected param. (in your case you set value as :id)

Hope it works